# Create an incremental count from a cumulative count by date segmented by another series in a Pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, date, increment

I have cumulative data (the series 'cumulative_count') in a date frame ('df1') that is segmented by the series 'state' and I want to create a new series in the data frame that shows incremental count by 'state'.

So:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-01-03','2020-01-03','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-04','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-05','2020-01-05'],'state': ['NJ','NY','CT','NJ','NY','CT','NJ','NY','CT'], 'cumulative_count': [1,3,5,3,6,7,19,15,20]})
```

...is transformed to have the new series added ('incremental count') where the incremental count is calculated by date but also segmented by state with the result generated being...

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-01-03','2020-01-03','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-04','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-05','2020-01-05'],'state': ['NJ','NY','CT','NJ','NY','CT','NJ','NY','CT'], 'cumulative_count': [1,3,5,3,6,7,19,15,20],'incremental_count': [1,3,5,2,3,2,16,9,13]})
```

Any recommendations on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your DataFrame is already sorted by `'date'`, you are looking to take the `diff` within each state group. Then `fillna` to get the correct value for the first date within each state.

```
df1['incremental_count'] = (df1.groupby('state')['cumulative_count'].diff()
                               .fillna(df1['cumulative_count'], downcast='infer'))

         date state  cumulative_count  incremental_count
0  2020-01-03    NJ                 1                  1
1  2020-01-03    NY                 3                  3
2  2020-01-03    CT                 5                  5
3  2020-01-04    NJ                 3                  2
4  2020-01-04    NY                 6                  3
5  2020-01-04    CT                 7                  2
6  2020-01-05    NJ                19                 16
7  2020-01-05    NY                15                  9
8  2020-01-05    CT                20                 13
```